# Apply OR clause in WHERE or HAVING in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a laravel project for building REST api. I am using eloquent to fatch data from database. I am facing issues in applying the OR condition in WHERE, HAVING etc. If there is only one where and one orWhere condition, it has no issues but here I am taking multiple where clause. Like if we write core mysql query we can write like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE uid = 1 
AND (id = 1 AND name = test1) OR (id = 2 AND name = test2);
```

But when we work with eloquent and if we use orWhere in models, for that we need to do something like

```
Model::select('*')->where('uid', '1')
->where('id', '1')
->where('name', 'test1')
->orWhere('uid', '1')
->where('id', '1')
->where('name', 'test1')
->get();
```

Sometimes when I try to make any search API that can search data baseed on numbers of parameter of the table, I need to write same code multiple time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in `eloquent` of parenthesis would be using a closure as the parameter of `where` or `orWhere`

`(a or b) and (c or d)` would be:

```
->where(function($q){
  $q->where(a)->orWhere(b);
})->where(function($q){
  $q->where(c)->orWhere(d);
});
```

and

`(a and b) or (c and d)` would be:

```
->where(function($q){
  $q->where(a)->where(b);
})->orWhere(function($q){
  $q->where(c)->where(d);
});
```

but

`a or b and c or d` would be:

```
->where(a)->orWhere(b)->where(c)->orWhere(d)
```

which is something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

Use [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping) or `orWhere()` closure for `parameter grouping`

```
Model::select('*')->where('uid', '1')->where(function($q){
       $q->where('id', '1')->where('name', 'test1')
    })->orWhere(function($q){
          $q->where('id', '1')->where('name', 'test1')
     })->get();
```

From Docs

> Passing a `Closure` into the `orWhere` method instructs the query builder to begin a constraint group. The Closure will receive a query builder instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be contained within the parenthesis group.

Comment: a bit of explanation and where [OrWhere](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orWhere) comes from perhaps can do good..

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This code will be helpfull for you

```
Model::where([['uid', '1'],['id', '1'],['name', 'test1']])
->orWhere([['uid', '1'],['id', '1'],['name', 'test1']])
->get();
```